# Why do links with # not work in Firefox and Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I am currently scripting a website as a school project. I had the idea to load the whole content in one file, but if you click on a link in the navigation, only the allowed content will show up. I did this with JavaScript, which reacts on the URL, so the URL has to change. When I click a link on my navigation. So I just made a # behind the href like this:

```
 <nav id="nav">
      <a id="ict" href="index.html#ict" onclick="refresher();" >Informatik</a>
      <a id="mmt" href="index.html#mmt" onclick="refresher();" >Multimediatechnik</a>
      <a id="gundd" href="index.html#gundd" onclick="refresher();" >Gestaltung und Design</a>
      <a id="daw" href="index.html#daw" onclick="refresher();" >Digital Artwork Gallery</a>
      <a id="about" href="index.html#about" onclick="refresher();" >&Uuml;ber mich</a>
  </nav>
```

This works fine on Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge, but the # in the URL doesn't change if you use Firefox or Safari.

I don't think that the JS is the issue here, but I'm not 100% sure, so here is the onclick_function:

```
function refresher(){
    location.reload()
}
```

Thank you for your Help!

Comment: With the way you have this setup, i'm not sure why you are using location.reload. Shouldn't you just be showing/hiding content? The content is already on the page, no need to reload, It just needs to be presented.

Comment: but how else do i get the js to reload? now it looks like this:
`document.getElementById('daw_gal').style.display = "block";`but this wont happen unless the js gets reloaded. Am i right with this? @kevin

Comment: the js wouldn't need to reload. you simply run the code that needs to run in that function you're calling.

Comment: now i get what you are saying, i will try and tell you if it worked. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

They do work. But, after they scroll the page correctly, `refresher` runs and scrolls the page to `-300`. Decide which behavior you want (the `href` or the `refresher` function) and use one of them, but not both.

Comment: Thank you. I deleted the part with the scrollTop, but i still have the problem, that the url doesn't change in firefox, but doeas in chrome. I cant delete the whole function because i need it for the js to reload, so all the containers i dont need get a `display:none`

Comment: @NicolasLang No, it's not just the single line about `scrollTop`, you need to remove the entire `onclick` and related function or the `href` because the two are fighting each other. You can't have both. Why do you need the page refreshed?

Comment: @NicolasLang I think that your real problem is that your solution to a larger problem is the wrong approach. You say something about making sure that elements don't wind up with `display:none`, but reloading the page is not the only way to ensure that. You  should edit your question and explain the larger scenario you are working with.